# PHP - Obtendo todas as imagens de um diretório e gerando no HTML

Tags: php, html

Tenho um projeto e existem várias pastas contendo arquivos de imagens pertencentes a galeria: Preciso otimizar isso obtendo todas as imagens de um determinado diretório e gerá-las no HTML.

Basicamente o projeto recebe o diretório em um parâmetro da URL, ficando dessa forma abaixo: `localhost/?g=diretorio1%2Fgaleria1%2F`.

Nesse caso todos os arquivos do diretório 'diretorio1/galeria1/' serão filtrados para aceitar somente arquivos de imagens e logo em seguida será gerado o código HTML `<a href=""><img src="diretorio1/galeria1/x" /></a>`. Onde *x = nome e extensão de cada arquivo de imagem*.

Não tenho muita noção de PHP, de preferência me orientem com artigos ou detalhem a resposta para que eu possa compreender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separando por partes:

### Como ler parametros da URL:

Essa informacão que passas no URL pode ser capturada via `$_GET`, aí vais ter de descodificar usando [`rawurldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

Por exemplo:

```
$parametro_g = $_GET['g'];
$diretoria = rawurldecode($parametro_g); // que é o mesmo que rawurldecode('diretorio1%2Fgaleria1%2F'); no exemplo que deste
```

Assim tens a diretoria guardada numa variável.

### Como ler só as imagens na diretoria e gerar o HTML

```
$diretoria = "diretorio1/galeria1/"; // esta linha não precisas é só um exemplo do conteudo que a variável vai ter

// selecionar só .jpg
$imagens = glob($diretoria . "*.jpg");

// fazer echo de cada imagem
foreach($imagens as $imagem){
  echo '<a href=""><img src="diretorio1/galeria1/'.$imagem.'" /></a>';
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado :-)

Comment: Pude compreender a maior parte, no caso como posso acrescentar a extensão png (\*.png) ? Seria glob($diretorio . "\*.jpg", $diretorio . "*.png") ?

Comment: Encontrei. É glob($diretorio . "*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

Comment: O correto seria somente listar imagens que estão no diretório.

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de usar `$_GET`, utilize `$_REQUEST`, com ele a mesma url suporta `POST` e `GET`.

**Da forma que usei o glob não precisa informar o caminho na url no img.**

```
<?php

    $caminho = rawurldecode($_REQUEST['g']);
        $img = glob($caminho."*.{jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
        $contador = count($img);

foreach($img as $img){
  echo '<a href=""><img src="'.$img.'" /></a>';
}
?>
```

Obs.: Exemplo acima, caso seja JPG, coloque a extensão que for usar.

**Caso deseje ler todos arquivos de imagem, mesmo de outras extensões pode agrupalos.**

```
<?php

    $caminho = rawurldecode($_REQUEST['g']);
        $img = glob($caminho."*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
        $contador = count($img);

foreach($img as $img){
  echo '<a href=""><img src="'.$img.'" /></a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Conforme citado acima, **rawurldecode** decodifica a URL codificada pelo navegador.